# 3:1 (or 1:3) interval, does it exist ? How to perform it from a C?

Tags: theory, acoustic-guitar, key, intervals

Given that a composed sound is composed of a fundamental frequency and its harmonics (multiples of the fundamental), we could easily image that a pitch (with a fundamenal frequency f) is played and then another pitch with fundamental frequency 3f is played. Wouldn't the resulting sound be highly agreable to hear ? I tend to think it would be agreable because all the harmonics 3f, 6f, 9f, and so on would "resonate".

What would be the name of such an interval (3:1 or 1:3 would be the ratio, but is there a name?) ?

For example, if I play a C (third fret on the second string of a guitar), what should be the next key I need to play in order to do a 3:1 (or 1:3) interval ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That C note is 3rd fret, **5th** string. They're always numbered thin to thick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wouldn't the resulting sound be highly agreable to hear ?

Likely yes. It is attributed to Pythagoras to discover that notes which frequency ratios can be expressed with small integers are consonant.

> What would be the name of such an interval (3:1 or 1:3 would be the ratio, but is there a name?) ?

Twelfth or an octave + fifth.

> For example, if I play a C (third fret on the second string of a guitar), what should be the next key I need to play in order to do a 3:1 (or 1:3) interval ?

I guess you mean C on the third fret of the **fifth** string? (Counting starts from the treble strings). The note would be G on the third fret of the first string.

See also Wikipedia article on [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(music)).

Comment: As a side note,  folks should visualize the fundamental as the entire string moving up and down;  the first harmonic as the upper half vibrating opposite to the lower half;  the second harmonic as the middle third opposite to teh top and bottom thirds, and so on.